# Rails sort by parent id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have `category` and `subcategory` tables

`category` - parent

```
  has_many :subcategories
```

`subcategory` - child with category_id key

```
  belongs_to :category
```

i want to sort by parent id like

```
subcategory=1 parentId=1

subcategory=2 parentId=1


 subcategory=122 parentId=1

 subcategory=232 parentId=1



  subcategory=12 parentId=2

  subcategory=18 parentId=2
```

and so on

i have tried

```
Subcategory.joins(:category).order('categories.id') and 


Subcategory.joins(:category).group(['subcategories.title','categories.id']).order('categories.id')
```

but it doesn't work

How i can sort it?

I don't care about subcategory order just need to set order by parentId

Comment: Do you want to group or order? The title says grouping but your desired output just seems to be a list of subcategories ordered/sorted by subcategory.category_id which could be done by a simple `Subcategory.select(:id, :category_id).order(:category_id)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you,

```
category_ids = SubCategory.joins(:category).select('*').order('category_id ASC')

category_ids.pluck('category.id') //check the category id's
```

Comment: it gives me `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "subcategories.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: now i have got `ORDER BY "position" is ambiguous`.I have position column in this tables

Comment: but we haven't take position in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Subcategory.select('category_id').group('category_id').order('id')

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on functionality similar to it. This simply worked for me:

```
ChildTable.order(:parent_id)
```